# How to add Crossed out line whn product is out of stock?

Tags: magento2.4.5

I just want to add crossed out lines when the product is out of stock.
This problem occurred after upgrading Magento 2.4.5. can anyone help me with this problem?

Current Result :

[image]

Expected Result :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Crossed-out lines can be added to the product page when a product is out of stock in Magento 2.4.5 by using the following steps:

1. Log in to the Magento Admin Panel and navigate to Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Inventory.
2. Select “Yes” for the “Display Out of Stock Products” setting.
3. Select “Yes” for the “Display Out of Stock Products with Strikethrough Price” setting.
4. Click “Save Config” at the top right of the page.

The crossed-out lines will now be displayed on the product page for products that are out of stock.

**Or**

You can use the below code to add crossed-out lines when the product is out of stock.

```
<script>
    require(['jquery', 'Magento_Catalog/js/price-box'], function($, priceBox){
        var isOutOfStock = false;
        $('span[data-price-type="finalPrice"]').each(function () {
            if ($(this).find("span.price-wrapper").find("span.price").html() == "") {
            isOutOfStock = true;
            }
        });
        if (isOutOfStock == true) {
            $('.price-box').css("text-decoration", "line-through");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry, but it is not related to my question, because the question is related swatches option. And your answer related price cross line.